# Is server_name really needed for default_server? (Nginx)

Tags: nginx

I tried the 4 cases of code with `default_server` below one by one in Nginx. The file `default.conf` with the code is located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

1st: With `server_name _;`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    return 500;
}
```

2nd: With a different server name(private ip) `server_name 10.0.0.0;` (My computer's private ip is `10.156.58.216`)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name 10.0.0.0;
    
    return 500;
}
```

3rd: With `server_name "";`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name "";

    return 500;
}
```

4th: Without `server name`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    return 500;
}
```

My computer's private ip is `10.156.58.216`.

[image]

Then, the results are all the same showing `500 Internal Server Error` page.

[image]

I think for `default server`, we don't need `server name`. So the 4th code without `server name` is fine to use.

4th: Without server name

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    return 500;
}
```

I ask again, Is `server name` really needed for `default server`?

Comment: create a new configuration and test it, however listen 80 is afaik enough to use ipv4 and v6

Comment: Related: [Should there be a `server_name` directive present if only one website is served with NGINX? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1141063/should-there-be-a-server-name-directive-present-if-only-one-website-is-served/1141180#1141180)

Answer (score 18):

From [the Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names):

> If no server_name is defined in a server block then nginx uses the
> empty name as the server name.

Regarding `server_name _;`, the same document states:

> There is nothing special about this name, it is just one of a myriad
> of invalid domain names which never intersect with any real name.

Answer (score 5):

The only time NGINX looks at the [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive and [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)'s `default_server` parameter during processing the configuration is when  there is more than one `server` block [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)ing on the same [`ip_address`:]`port`. (It's also worth pointing out that there can be more than one `default_server` declaration in one config - one per [`ip_address`:]`port`.)

If a `server` block stands alone in an active configuration (i.e., there are no other `server` blocks listening on the same port, such as 80), then all of your examples can omit

- the `default_server` parameter

  (because they are the default by default - and there is no other `server` block around to process requests on port 80 anyway)
- the `server_name` directive

  (as they are the only `server` blocks for port 80, so NGINX won't even bother comparing `server_name` with a request's `Host` header: all the requests would be directed there anyway)

### When does the `server_name` directive need to be used in tandem with `default_server`?

One example is when you need a catch-all block to dismiss any connection that is not explicitly handled in other `server` blocks.

For a concrete example, here's an HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect:

```
##########################
# HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect #
##########################
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ourdomain.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

##########################
# HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect #
##########################
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name another.doma.in;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# ... more `server` blocks listening on port 80

#############
# CATCH-ALL #
#############
server {
   listen 80 default_server; 
   server_name _;

   return 404;
}
```

In this case, the catch-all block **must have** both:

- a `server_name` declaration that doesn't match any valid domain

  When NGINX sees that there are more than one block for port 80, it compares the request's `Host` field to `server_name` to choose the right one. If none match, then the request will be routed to the `default_server`. (See [How NGINX processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and the flowchart at the bottom.)

  It's important this block **does not match anything** because it can be anywhere in the config file, so it can accidentally process a request intended for another one. (Plus, the point is to explicitly configure the domains / IP addresses the server will handle, and deny everything else.)
- a `listen ... default_server ...` declaration

  If the catch-all block for that [`ip_address`:]`port` is the first one in the file, it will implicitly become the default server for it. Then again, it can also be anywhere in the config, plus it never hurts to be explicit.

[image: flowchart for processing NGINX configurations]